# pine script is making problems/doesn't recognize "sma"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I let me write a short pine script v5 with an alarm by chatgtp 4.

//@version=5

// Berechnung der SMMA (100, Close)
smma = sma(close, 100)

// Definieren Sie die Bedingungen für den Alarm
price_near_smma = abs(close - smma) < 0.5 // Preis liegt in der Nähe von SMMA (100, Close)
price_cross_smma = crossover(close, smma) or crossunder(close, smma) // Preis durchquert SMMA (100, Close)

// Auslösen des Alarms, wenn die Bedingungen erfüllt sind
if price_near_smma or price_cross_smma
alert("Preis nähert sich oder durchquert SMMA (100, Close)")

But pine script doesn't know "sma". when I switch to pine script version 4, it recognizes "sma" and no error message occurs. therefore other error messages occur.

This is the error message: Fehler/Error in 4:8 Could not find function or function reference 'sma'

Can anyone help me please?

I expected the script is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do:

I needed to change "sma" to "ta.sma", "abs" to "math.abs", and "crossover" to "ta.crossover" and so on.

I needed to add this line, either: indicator("Mein Indikator", overlay=true)

Now it was accepted by trading view.